# Windows client error for DB2 10.5 fp3 DATA BASE Connection refused:Error:SQL30081N and SQLSTATE IS 08001

Tags: db2, db2-luw

When we connect to database we got error in windows client machine.
Error:SQL30081N and SQLSTATE IS 08001.

SERVER:HP-UX DB2 10.5 FP3

Please suggest on this.

Comment: How do you connect?

Comment: your server, network, firewall are all ok.  what is the result                             "telnet databaseserverIP 50000"

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google suggests this may be the result of a firewall blocking the connection: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21503305

Comment: the link walks you through open the port